# Facebook Connect FB.getLoginStatus issues ~ JS SDK

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook-graph-api, facebook

I am having trouble executing the FB.getLoginStatus() method directly. When a user clicks the action button, I call the FB.getLoginStatus() however, this returns "Undefined". When I reload the page FB.getLoginStatus() works how it should. How can I get use of the FB.getLoginStatus() on demand with in the page. I have attached my source code.

The Function _checkFBStatus() calls the FB.getLoginStatus() when the user clicks the action button.

This click event is where everything takes place. I had to implement a hack in order to get this to work. Once the FB.login callback executes I redirect to the same page and call FB.getLoginStatus(). I would rather not use this hack:

```
        $('ul.fb')
            .click( function( event )
            {
                if( _checkFBStatus() )
                {
                    _getFriends();

                }else
                {
                    _login();   

                }   
            }
        );
```

Here is the full souce code:

```
head.ready(function() {
       // --------------------------------------------------------------------

       /**
        * execute the facebook events
        * @desc     Facebook events executions with custom callbacks
        */


    (function($){

       // --------------------------------------------------------------------

       /**
        * Default vars
        * @desc     set up the default variables
        */

        var
        fql         = 'SELECT first_name,last_name, pic_small , uid, is_app_user FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend where uid1 = {0} )  AND is_app_user=1',
        fbOptions   =           
                {
                    appId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', 
                    status: true, 
                    cookie: true, 
                    xfbml: true
                },

        e           = document.createElement('script');
        e.src       = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
        e.async     = true;
        document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);



        window.fbAsyncInit = function() 
        {
            FB.init( fbOptions );

            FB
            .getLoginStatus( function( response ) 
                {   
                    if( MYNYTE.getURLVars()['success'].length > 0 ) _getFriends();              
                }
            );


        };


       // --------------------------------------------------------------------

       /**
        * Click initial action
        * @desc     Start the facebook process
        * @acces    public  
        */




        $('ul.fb')
            .click( function( event )
            {
                if( _checkFBStatus() )
                {
                    _getFriends();

                }else
                {
                    _login();   

                }   
            }
        );


       // --------------------------------------------------------------------

       /**
        * Check Status
        * @desc     Check the status of the user
        * @acces    private 
        */


        function _checkFBStatus()
        {
            FB
            .getLoginStatus( function( response ) 
                {   
                    if (response.status == 'connected') 
                    {
                        return true;
                    } 
                    else 
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            );      

        }

       // --------------------------------------------------------------------

       /**
        * Login
        * @desc     Try to log the user in and then call the getFriends method
        * @acces    private 
        */


        function _login()
        {
            FB
            .login( function( response ) 
                {
                    window.location = '/connections?success=true#connections';
                }, 
                {scope: 'email'}
            );  
        }



       // --------------------------------------------------------------------

       /**
        * Get Friends
        * @desc     Try to get the user's frends that are associated with MyNyte
        */


        function _getFriends()
        {
            FB.api('/me', 
                function( response ) 
                {
                    var query = FB.Data.query( fql, response.id );

                    FB.Data.waitOn([ query ], 
                        function( fbReturn ) {

                            var ret = _parseFBReturn( fbReturn );

                        }//end callback

                    );//end fb JS Wait On

                }// end FB api callback

            );//end api 

        }//end getFriends


       // --------------------------------------------------------------------

       /**
        * Parse The return FB
        * @desc     Try to parse the return facebook query
        * @params   array 
        * @acces    private 
        */



        function _parseFBReturn( data )
        {
            var 
            i, j            = 0,
            outerArgLength  = data.length,
            innerArgLength  = 0;

            for( i = 0; i <= outerArgLength; i++ )
            {
                innerArgLength = data[ i ].length;

                for( j = 0; j <= innerArgLength; j++ )
                {
                    _writeHTML( data[ i ][ j ] );
                }//end inner for

            }//end outer for



            return true;
        }

       // --------------------------------------------------------------------

       /**
        * Write the facebook HTML
        * @desc     Write the html for the facebook import
        * @params   array 
        * @acces    private 
        */


        function _writeHTML( user )
        {
            $('div#facebook-friends')
                .append(
                    $( '<h3 />')
                    .text( user.first_name + ' ' + user.last_name )
                )       
                .append( 
                    $( '<img />' )
                    .attr('src', user.pic_small )
                );

        }



    })(jQuery);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason you don't use the response from the FB.login?  It should contain the same connected info as calling FB.getLoginStatus.

Comment: I would rather FB.getLoginStatus(), this seems to be the correct way to do this

Comment: It depends upon what you're trying to accomplish.  You should be able to get a reliable response by calling FB.getLoginStatus in the callback section of your FB.init function.

Comment: It doesn't seem that the FB.init has a callback.

Comment: Sorry you're right.  I created a function that put's a callback in the correct spot.  Try calling after the FB.init call inside of the window.fbAsyncInit function.